# How to change values of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array 'X' of shape(826,2). I have another numpy array of zeros 'X_expanded' of shape(X.shape[0], 6). I want to replace the elements of the X_expanded with feature0, feature1, feature0^2, feature1^2, feature1*feature2, 1 of the array X.

For example

```
X = np.array([
    [0,0],
    [1,0],
    [2.61,-1.28],
    [-0.59,2.1]
])
```

I want X_expanded to be

```
([[ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.],
  [ 1.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  1.],
  [ 2.61  , -1.28  ,  6.8121,  1.6384, -3.3408,  1.],
  [-0.59  ,  2.1   ,  0.3481,  4.41  , -1.239 ,  1.]])
```

Comment: `What is the best way to do this?` So, you have some ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
X = np.array([
    [0,0],
    [1,0],
    [2.61,-1.28],
    [-0.59,2.1]
])


X_e = np.zeros((X.shape[0], 6)) 

# Retain first two columns from X
X_e[:,:2] = X
# Set 2nd and 3rd columns equals to squares of X's 1st and 2nd column 
X_e[:,2:4] = X**2
# Set 5th column equal to product of X's 1st and 2nd columns
X_e[:,4] = X[:,0] * X[:,1]
# Set 6th column to all ones
X_e[:,5] = 1
```

Comment: `X_e[:,2:4] = X**2`

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**. Consider providing an explanation along with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either construct an array from scratch or create an empty array and fill the values with slices

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[2.61,-1.28],[-0.59,2.1]])
Xe = np.block([X,X**2,np.prod(X,axis=1,keepdims=1),np.ones([X.shape[0],1])])
```

Comment: `np.concatenate(..., axis=-1)` will be faster here

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to horizontally stack the columns as you need.

```
X_extended = np.hstack((X, X**2, np.prod(X,axis=1,keepdims=1), np.ones([X.shape[0],1])))
print(X_extended)

[[ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      1.    ]
 [ 1.      0.      1.      0.      0.      1.    ]
 [ 2.61   -1.28    6.8121  1.6384 -3.3408  1.    ]
 [-0.59    2.1     0.3481  4.41   -1.239   1.    ]]
```

---

**Timing:**

```
X = np.random.random((100000,2))

# np.hstack() @akilat90
%timeit np.hstack((X, X**2, np.prod(X,axis=1,keepdims=1), np.ones([X.shape[0],1])))    
100 loops, best of 3: 4.92 ms per loop

# np.block() @percusse
%timeit np.block([X,X**2,np.prod(X,axis=1,keepdims=1),np.ones([X.shape[0],1])])
100 loops, best of 3: 5.01 ms per loop

# @Bert's Answer
def bert(X):
   X_e = np.zeros((X.shape[0], 6)) 

   X_e[:,:2] = X 
   X_e[:,2] = X[:,0] * X[:,0]
   X_e[:,3] = X[:,1] * X[:,1]
   X_e[:,4] = X[:,0] * X[:,1]
   X_e[:,5] = 1 

   return X_e

%timeit bert(X)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.63 ms per loop

# list comprehension @Joe Iddon
%timeit np.array([[i, j, i**2, j**2, i*j] for i,j in X])
1 loop, best of 3: 246 ms per loop
```

Although a  bit verbose, the answer by @Bert seems to be the fastest whereas `np.hstack()` and `np.block()` are almost the same and list comprehension is the slowest.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a `list-comprehension` which is very readable IMO:

```
np.array([[i, j, i**2, j**2, i*j] for i,j in X])
```

which gives:

```
array([[ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
       [ 1.    ,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
       [ 2.61  , -1.28  ,  6.8121,  1.6384, -3.3408],
       [-0.59  ,  2.1   ,  0.3481,  4.41  , -1.239 ]])
```